# How to find the previous 12Months date starting from last Month

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to create a query to find number of occurrences in a list in a SAS dataset, for the past 12 Months starting from Last Month

I have created the macro below to be used in my WHERE clause:

```
%let cur_date = %sysfunc(today(), date9.); 
%let pre_date2 = %sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(today()), -1, End)),%sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(today()), -12, End)) date9.)));  
%put &pre_date4;
```

I would appreciate if you can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your data. Makes it easier to provide a usable code answer.

Comment: You create `pre_date2`, then %put `pre_date4` - assume is a typo?  Also, missing a comma before last `date9.`.  Can you show the where clause you would hope to use this macro variable?

Answer (score 1):

You need two macro variables: one for the end of the prior month and one for the first day 12 months prior to last month.

```
%let last_month     = %sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(today()), -1, E) );
%let last_12_months = %sysfunc(intnx(month, &last_month., -12, B) );
```

Now you can run your query using `between`:

```
where date BETWEEN &last_month. AND &last_12_months.;
```

Example:

```
data have;
    do i = -36 to 0;
        date = intnx('month', today(), i, 'B');
        output;
    end;

    format date date9.;
    drop i;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    where date BETWEEN &last_month. AND &last_12_months.;
run;
```

Output:

```
date
01OCT2020
01NOV2020
01DEC2020
01JAN2021
01FEB2021
01MAR2021
01APR2021
01MAY2021
01JUN2021
01JUL2021
01AUG2021
01SEP2021
```